# What is the state of the art of visualizing bifurcations for "difficult" dynamical systems?

Tags: reference-request, ds.dynamical-systems, complex-dynamics, visualization

This question is related to [my other recent question on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/190940/is-there-an-efficient-way-to-visualize-the-bifurcation-locus-of-this-family-of-f) (although I am not confident that the dynamical system described in that other question is actually "difficult," in the sense that I will describe here).

For a parameterized family of functions on a metric space $M$,

$$f_\lambda:M\mapsto M$$

(where $\lambda$ is either also from $M$ or is from some other metric space, as long as it's possible to talk about "nearby" parameters) I would like to visualize the parameters $\lambda$ for which the dynamics of the iterates of $f_\lambda$ are unstable.

Some families are not very difficult to analyze because their global dynamics happen to be governed by the dynamics of one, or a few, orbits.  In particular, when $M$ is the Riemann Sphere and the $f_\lambda$ are rational functions it is frequently (always?) possible to find the bifurcation locus by investigating the orbits of the critical points.

My question is:

> How are the bifurcations visualized in the more general case?

For example, what if $M$ is a less convenient metric space, or the global dynamics are not governed by a finite number of orbits, or $f_\lambda$ is given numerically?

In the linked question I suggested a technique for estimating stability by essentially running thousands of image comparisons; but it's a naive method, really nothing more than a brute force way to detect when the dynamics are sensitive to perturbation of the parameter.  I think better methods must exist I would like to see references for those methods.

As an aside: I am taking for granted that the parameter space is amenable to visualization *at all*, but there are plenty of interesting parameter spaces for which visualization is not trivial.  That might be an interesting problem in and of itself, but I am trying to restrain the scope of this MO question.

Comment: I'm not sure there's much to be said about arbitrary families of *functions* on arbitrary metric spaces.  Basically, anything could happen at any time.  There is no stability of any form. Perhaps you want a more restricted context than that?

Comment: @RyanBudney I see what you mean, but I'm not sure what level of restriction is appropriate, which is why I tried to phrase the question in a (perhaps excessively) general way.  Certainly there is a great deal of structure if we restrict to meromorphic functions on $\mathbb{C}$ (or on the Riemann sphere) but that's probably *too* restricted.  Even the system in the linked question operates in the broader context of $\mathbb{C}^2$, and yet appears to have inherited some structure from one-variable complex dynamics.  I would be happy with references to restricted contexts that admit better tools.